# Creating authenticated Python API call

Tags: python, json

I'm a little, well lot!, lost with how to make an API call using Python. I have done a number as trials successfully but now I am trying to build an app I am lost. The instructions below is all I am provided. I am unsure how to get beyond my code

```
MHL = urlopen('http://new.mhl.nsw.gov.au/services/mhladas/getAccessKey.json.php')
```

which then asks for username etc.

```
eg {u'access_key': None, u'error': u'No username has been entered'}
```

How do I send my details back to be authenticated by their server? and then have the request returned with the data I want? Happy to be directed to a tutorial on this or any help is truly appreciated. Not understanding how to convert their instructions into relevant Python code

4.1 Login – Request access key
You need to make a login request to begin using the service. This login provides 
you with a limited time access key. You need to provide this key for any 
subsequent requests you make.

```
http://new.mhl.nsw.gov.au/services/mhladas/getAccessKey.json.php
```

> Request
>       {"username":"user@myserver.com","password":"abc123"}
>   Example response
>       {"access_key":" MjAxMy0wNS0x…”,”error":null}
>
> > 4.2 Get Station List
> >     Use this function to list the stations you have available to you.
> >         http://new.mhl.nsw.gov.au/services/mhladas/getStationList.json.php
> >     Request
> >         {"username":"test@mhl.nsw.gov.au","access_key": " MjAxMy0wNS0x…"}

Answer (score 1):

Information you have provided in the question is not clear. I am assuming you have to post request with username and password parameter. First of all use python request to do such things easily. `pip install requests`. Then try this.

```
payload = {'username': 'user@myserver.com', 'password': 'abc123'}
r = requests.post("http://new.mhl.nsw.gov.au/services/mhladas/getAccessKey.json.php", data = payload)
print r
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a POST with `urllib`, you need to encode data with `urlencode`, and pass it as param to `urlopen`

```
import urllib

data = urllib.urlencode({"username":"buddy","password":"inches"})
post = urllib.urlopen('http://new.mhl.nsw.gov.au/services/mhladas/getStationList.json.php', data)

print post.code
print post.read()
```

Another way is to use `requests` as Sar009 suggested

Comment: I get a 200 return which is good using the requests code                                                                   But it says I should get a responses like this {"access_key":" MjAxMy0wNS0x…”,”error":null} which includes an API Key that I need to use in all other requests such as                                                                     {"username":"test@mhl.nsw.gov.au","access_key": " MjAxMy0wNS0x…"}     Not sure what else I need if I am posting userid and password. I seem to not be able to get that key no matter what I do.